# Unity ECS - Not visible in Scene View

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-dots, unity-ecs

I have a simple Unity project using the [Entities](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@1.0/manual/index.html) and [Entities Graphics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities.graphics@1.0/manual/index.html) packages, and it is working fine in the Game View but not visible in the Scene View. Have I missed a step?

Answer (score 6):

There is an option in `Preferences -> Entities -> Scene View Mode`.

Change this from `Authoring Data` to `Runtime Data`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Unity Editor 2022.3.X, from menu options go to **Edit** -> **Preferences** -> **Entities** -> **Baking**.

Click the dropdown menu and change **Authoring Data** to **Runtime Data**.

[image: Unity Preferences Entities]